# JSON for complex and simple data type

Tags: json, vb.net, wcf

Im developing a WCF service that accepts JSON.  My method signature accepts 2 parameters, a complex object and a simple type. For all intents and purposes below, assume "servicecredentials" has 2 properties, "username" and "password". I have valid JSON, but when I use a tool like postman I get the error "Expected to find an attribute with name 'type' and value 'object'. Found value 'array'.'"

How should this JSON be posted to the method?

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(method:="POST")>
Function GetStuff(ByVal creds As servicecredentials, ByVal acctNum As String)
```

The JSON Im posting

```
[
    {
        "UserName": "someUSer",
        "Password": "p@ssw0Rd"
    },
    {
        "acctNum": "X12362"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[]` brackets indicate a `JSON Array`, the `{}` brackets indicate a `JSON Object`. If you encompass the array with the `{}` brackets it will be an object, which is what it seems to be looking for.

Example:

```
{
    "data": [
                {
                    "UserName": "someUSer",
                    "Password": "p@ssw0Rd"
                },
                {
                    "acctNum": "X12362"
                }
            ]
}
```

The exact internal structure of the JSON depends on how the method will process the data. The error is simply stating that the JSON is not encompassed by an object.